# adding backorder message to the order email

Tags: backorder

I've enabled backorders, and it works as expected - showing a message in the checkout when required.

How can I show the same message in the order email that is sent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add it to the Email:

```
app/design/frontend/default/<your_template>/template/email/order/items/order/default.phtml
```

or

app/design/frontend/base/default/template/email/order/items/order/default.phtml

You can add this code:

```
<?php if ($_item->getQtyBackordered()): ?>
  Your message
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: that's great - thanks! Do you know the code that replicates the original message in the checkout? (ie, tells you the number that is on backorder)

Comment: I don't understand where you say, you can specify it more, please.

Comment: by default, when I am in the checkout, I get a message under the ordered item that says "* "iphone 5" is not available in the requested quantity. 3 of the items will be backordered."

Comment: $_item->getQtyBackordered() returns you the number of products will be backordered. In your example the value of $_item->getQtyBackordered() will be 3.