# Magento 2 : Add Additional Cart Item Notice to Transactional Emails (Out of stock notice)

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, email-templates, transactional-mail, backorder

I am relatively new to Magento and am developing a site on version 2.2.5. I am trying to figure out how to display the cart item message notice in the transactional email.

This is the notice that is displayed on the shopping cart page if there is not enough inventory to fulfill the order (See attached image).
[image]
I've copied `Magento_Sales/templates/email/items.phtml` to my child theme folder and can make edits there. It seems that the code for this notice is located in `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/templates/cart/additional/info.phtml`, but I am not sure how to display it on the emails.

Has anyone successfully displayed the out of stock notice in the new order email? I would greatly appreciate any assistance. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone is still looking for this solution, I found information about this and got it to work for our site:

This shows where to put it: 
[Which file hold this layout {{layout handle="sales_email_order_items" order=$order area="frontend"}}](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/242451/which-file-hold-this-layout-layout-handle-sales-email-order-items-order-ord?rq=1)

This is the code I placed in the page: 
[adding backorder message to the order email](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/31895/adding-backorder-message-to-the-order-email)