# Which file hold this layout {{layout handle="sales_email_order_items" order=$order area="frontend"}}

Tags: magento2, email-templates, magento2.2.2, order-email

Is there anyone knows how or where to update the file for the email order notification template.

```
{{layout handle="sales_email_order_items" order=$order area="frontend"}}
```

Thank you,
JM

Answer (score 7):

You can update in the file :

> vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/templates/email/items.phtml

Or override in your custom module :

> app\design\frontend\our-template\default\layout\sales.xml
>
> app\design\frontend\our-template\default\template\sales\order\items.phtml

You can find all emails template in the folder path :

> vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/email/

And for the item of order email template :

> vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/templates/email/items/order/default.phtml

Comment: Thanks, but where I can update {{layout handle="sales_email_order_items" order=$order area="frontend"}}, I want to update the sku label. http://prntscr.com/kv79g6

Comment: You can check my screen : http://prntscr.com/kv7c0v

Comment: Cheers!! it works.

Comment: Great, you can accept my answer

Comment: I already upvoted it.

Comment: Thanks you, can you accept like : http://prntscr.com/kv7f70

Comment: I can't see it. Maybe my reputation is low.

Comment: Okay, no problem, happy coding !

Answer (score 3):

New Magento (2.4.3-p2 in this moment) requires following update in the email template, to show order line items in the Order Confirmation email:

From:

```
{{layout handle="sales_email_order_items" order=$order area="frontend"}}
```

To:

```
{{layout handle="sales_email_order_items" order_id=$order_id area="frontend"}}
```

Comment: Correct information! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

How can we call this layout in phtml block which we added in email template ?