# Magento 2: How can I align columns in sales order template

Tags: magento2

i wanted to align the column for items qty and price so that they can be space out and not grouping together as it is now.

I know which file to edit, but how to "crack open" the {{layout handle="sales_email_order_items" order=$order area="frontend"}}

Does anyone know how I can align this info into a proper table?

[image: Sales oreder]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copy `vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/templates/email/items.phtml` file to `app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Sales/view/frontend/templates/email/items.phtml` file and do your design changes in this file

Below file is for the item of order email template:

```
vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/templates/email/items/order/default.phtml
```

You can change it by copying it to your theme `app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Sales/view/frontend/templates/email/items/order/default.phtml`

You can find all emails templates by following the below path in your Magento directory.

```
vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/email/
```

> Reference [Which file hold this layout {{layout handle="sales_email_order_items" order=$order area="frontend"}}](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/242451/which-file-hold-this-layout-layout-handle-sales-email-order-items-order-ord?rq=1)

**Hope this helps!!!**

Comment: Have you tried this @Ben?

Comment: Dear Sumit, finally we got it done. It worked for us as described by you. Thank you very much!